# цикл for с несколькими переменными

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for

Есть ли возможность или аналогичная функция, которая будет делать примерно так?

```
massiv = ['hello', 'world']

for c1, c2 in massiv[0], vassiv[1]:
    print(c1, c2) #OUT: h w
    if c1 == c2:
        ...
```

Предположим, у нас есть список, в котором n строк или других типов данных. Есть ли способ одновременно перебрать значения каждой строки, например, для сравнения?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Смотря что требуется. Сравнение неудачный пример, т.к. строки можно сравнивать через `==` без итерации. Возможно подойдет функция `zip` или `zip_longest` из `itertools`.

```
>>> for i in zip(*massiv):
...  print(i)
... 
('h', 'w')
('e', 'o')
('l', 'r')
('l', 'l')
('o', 'd')
```

Comment: Функция `zip_longest` не в `collections`, а в [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

Comment: @wchistow спасибо, исправил.

Comment: А можете дать ссылку на нормальное объяснение про zip, пожалуйста? В инете не все понятно… как я понял, он объединяет 2 списка/кортежа/словаря?

Comment: @SatoriDev zip итерирует (проходит по) каждому из итерируемых объектов (например строки), которые подаются ему на вход. И каждый шаг строит кортеж из элементов, взятых из каждого объекта. Пример кортежа - ('h', 'w'). Это может быть не два объекта, а больше. Причем он это делает "лениво", т.е. только когда его просят сделать следующий шаг. В нашем случае цикл for запрашивает данные полностью пока они могут быть предоставлены функцией zip.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за объяснение(хоть тур проходил и знаю, что благодарить не следует)))